# Error: [MC] Reading from private effective user settings

Tags: ios, swift, settings, textfield

I have set `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to disabled, yet I am still getting this error whenever I try typing in a text field. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message is not an error, this is simply a (somewhat buggy) log message in the debug console stating that the app is reading from user settings. You can safely ignore it.